# How do I access this JSON API data in Ruby?

Tags: json, ruby

I am writing a short Ruby program that is going to take a zipcode and return the names of cities within 2 miles of that zipcode. I successfully called an API and was able to parse the JSON data, but I'm unsure how to access the 'city' key.

```
url = API call (not going to replicate here since it requires a key)

uri = URI(url)

response = Net::HTTP.get(uri)
JSON.parse(response)
```

Here's what my JSON looks like.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "zip": "08225",
      "city": "Northfield",
      "county": "Atlantic",
      "state": "NJ",
      "distance": "0.0"
    },
    {
      "zip": "08221",
      "city": "Linwood",
      "county": "Atlantic",
      "state": "NJ",
      "distance": "1.8"
    }
  ]
}
```

I've been trying to access 'city' like this:

```
response['result'][0]['city']
```

This appears to be incorrect. Also tried

```
response[0][0]['city']
```

And a couple of other permutations of the same code.

How can I get the value 'Northfield' out of the JSON data?

Answer (score 6):

You're almost there, just use `results` instead of `result` on the result of `JSON.parse(response)` instead of on `response`:

```
JSON.parse(response)["results"][0]["city"]
#=> "Northfield"
```

Answer (score 2):

JSON parse will create a hash then you can target the results which is an array of hashes, like so:

```
hash = JSON.parse(response)
hash['results'].select{|h| h['city'] == 'Northfield'}
```

Or if you only care about the results:

```
array = JSON.parse(response)['results']
array.select{|a| a['city' == 'Northfield'} #
```

To get just a single data point from the data, you might select one item in the array and then the key of the value you want:

```
array[0]['city']
```

For all the cities

```
cities = array.map{|k,v| k['city']}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo error, instead of `response['result']` you can use it like `response[:results]`.

And if you want to get the value of `city` key from all the hash, then `response['result'][0]['city']` will not work.

After parsing response you will get an array of hashes, i.e

```
[{:zip=>"08225", :city=>"Northfield", :county=>"Atlantic", :state=>"NJ", :distance=>"0.0"}, {:zip=>"08221", :city=>"Linwood", :county=>"Atlantic", :state=>"NJ", :distance=>"1.8"}]
```

And if you want to fetch the values of key `city` from all the hash then you can try this steps

```
response[:results].map{|x| x[:city]}
```

which will give the result

```
["Atlantic", "Atlantic"]
```

Comment: Note: `JSON.parse` will give you a hash with string keys, not symbol keys. Right?